# What is this insect? 6 legs and red body

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm in Brazil, southeast region, urban area. I've found these 6 legged insects with red bodies and black heads. They have long antennae (about as long as their limbs) and they walk around like ants, but slower. Their bodies are about 1.5mm in length.

I have also found a cluster of what I imagine are eggs they laid or got out from (there were 5 or so next to them last night).

Can someone identify them?

[image: one bug]
[image: two bugs]
[image: eggs]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! If possible please try to get clearer pictures and then [edit] them] into your question — closeups from multiple angles will improve your chances of getting a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These appear to be the nymphs of the red-shouldered bug (*[Jadera hematoloma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jadera_haematoloma)*), which eat the seeds of the Sapindaceae family (Soapberry family) throughout South America, Central America and the southern parts of North America.

There is a close-up picture of one of these at [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/385750), and further images [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/3601) on the same website.